# Trying to add features and push changes on an Application using AWS-amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm building an App in my mac using the creacte-react-app boilerplate and AWS-Amplify to build the backend. When trying to push changes or add feature to the project I a console error.

Example:

```
amplify push
✖ There was an error pulling the backend environment dev.
An error occurred during the push operation: Cannot read property 'mkdir' of undefined$
```

Its all I'm getting... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Node V10 is not compatible... once I upgraded to Node v12 I was able to push and add new features.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens if you change some things in the project directory. Ensure you do not have an additional error about missing path. If you do have missing path error, kindly check this folder-amplify in you project and change the directory in the file local-env-info.json

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30356519)